# MacOSX create a password-protected zip that not listing content on preview?

Tags: macos, terminal, zip

I can use `zip -er FOLDER.zip FOLDER` to zip my files with password-protected. But while extracting, the listing info can be preview before user entering the password. So, how can I do it in Terminal, to create a zip file that will encrypt the archive's listing too?

I knew this can be done on a Windows' WinRAR compressor by an option, but I want to do it in MacOSX.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using p7zip, a POSIX port of 7-zip which works so well on Windows. It is available via [homebrew](http://brew.sh), from [here](http://brewformulas.org/P7zip).

So, if you want to create an archive with encrypted metadata and headers, use the `-mhe=on` option like this

```
7z a -mhe=on -pmy_password archive.7z folderToArchive
```

Here is a little session, showing creation and extraction of a zip:

```
$ 7z a -mhe=on -pmy_password archive.7z x

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)
Scanning
Updating archive archive.7z
Everything is Ok

$ 7z e archive.7z

7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)
Processing archive: archive.7z
Enter password (will not be echoed) :
```